# Appending values in a specific format to a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists. I am writing a condition to find index values when `MaxPrnew > Pr_cap_t` and appending it as shown below. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
Pr_cap_t=[5051.061086369891,
 5046.295040175788,
 5072.5758312061325,
 5055.713625152885,
 5056.625327627877]

MaxPrnew=[241.08095445711552,
 1726.9903228626436,
 1232.262749719154,
 484.3360494454877,
 1232.262749719154]


Cond_t=[]
false_indices = [[]]

for i in range(len(MaxPrnew)):  
    Cond1 = MaxPrnew[i] > Pr_cap_t[i]
    Cond_t.append(Cond1) 
    if not Cond1: 
        false_indices.append(i)

print("false_indices =",false_indices)
```

The current output is

```
false_indices = [[], 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The expected output is

```
false_indices = [[], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: Set `false_indices = [[], []]` and append indices to `false_indices[1]`.

Comment: What's the purpose of the empty list at index 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Pr_cap_t=[5051.061086369891,
 5046.295040175788,
 5072.5758312061325,
 5055.713625152885,
 5056.625327627877]

MaxPrnew=[241.08095445711552,
 1726.9903228626436,
 1232.262749719154,
 484.3360494454877,
 1232.262749719154]

k = [x for x,y in enumerate(zip(Pr_cap_t, MaxPrnew)) if y[0] > y[1]] # your program logic can be used in a list comprehension

false_indices = [[]]

false_indices.append(k)

false_indices
#[[], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: and why not iterate over zipped `Pr_cap_t` and `MaxPrnew`?

Comment: yes you are right! `zip` and `enumerate` can be used interchangeably if the length of both lists are same.

Comment: No, I mean `enumerate(zip(Pr_cap_t, MaxPrnew))`, because they need the  inndex

Comment: `[idx for idx, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(Pr_cap_t, MaxPrnew)) if x > y]`